Как предотвратить исключение Flood control в aiogram3.x?
Есть телеграмм бот, который достаЁт данные группы в телеграмме nickname и id пользователя.
КОД:
@router.message(Form.waiting_for_group_link)
async def get_group_link(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    global collecting_ids
    collecting_ids = True
    link = message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[-1]
    counter = 0

    try:
        await client.start()
        async with client:
            formatted_text = (
                f"╔════════════════════════╗\n"
                f"║ <b> Собираем участников:</b> <i>0</i> \n"
                f"╚════════════════════════╝"
            )
            status_message = await message.answer(formatted_text, parse_mode='html')
            entity = await client.get_entity(link)

            async for msg in client.iter_messages(entity):
                if not collecting_ids:
                    break

                if msg.sender_id and msg.sender_id not in [user['id'] for user in collected_user_ids]:
                    username = msg.sender.username if msg.sender.username else "Unknow"
                    collected_user_ids.append({'id': msg.sender_id, 'username': username})
                    counter += 1

                    formatted_text = (
                        f"╔════════════════════════╗\n"
                        f"║ <b> Собираем участников:</b> <i>{counter}</i> \n"
                        f"╚════════════════════════╝"
                    )

                    await status_message.edit_text(formatted_text, parse_mode='html')
                    if counter % 28 == 0:
                        await asyncio.sleep(2)

            await status_message.edit_text("<b>Парсинг успешно завершен ✅</b>\n\n<i> Отправляю файл...</i>",
                                           parse_mode='html')
            sleep(3)
            await status_message.delete()

            with open("RESULTS.txt", "w") as file:
                file.write(f"{'ID':<20} {'NICKNAME':<20}\n")
                file.write("=====================================\n")

                for index, user in enumerate(collected_user_ids, start=1):
                    file.write(f"{index}{'.':<3} {user['id']:<15} @{user['username']:<20}\n")

            if collected_user_ids:
                document = FSInputFile(path='RESULTS.txt')
                await message.answer_document(document=document, caption=f"<b>️ Парсинг готов!</b>", parse_mode='html')
            else:
                await message.answer("Не удалось собрать ID участников.")

    except FloodWaitError as e:
        await message.answer(f"<b><i>⚠️ Слишком много запросов. Пожалуйста, подождите {e.seconds} секунд.</i></b>",
                            parse_mode='html')

    await state.clear()
    await message.answer(" Вы вернулись в главное меню.", reply_markup=main_menu)


В телеграмм документации было написано что бот может отправлять 30 запросов в секунду, поэтому я добавил это:
if counter % 28 == 0:
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

Думая что это предотвратить исключение Flood control, но он все ровно выпадает. Что можно сделать чтобы это самое исключение не возникало.
ЛОГИ:
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher:Start polling
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher:Run polling for bot @chat_hunterbot id=7815606139 - 'ChatHunter'
INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=478623879 is handled. Duration 383 ms by bot id=7815606139
INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=478623880 is handled. Duration 110 ms by bot id=7815606139
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connecting to 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull...
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection to 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull complete!
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Disconnecting from 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull...
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Disconnection from 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull complete!
INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=478623881 is not handled. Duration 23757 ms by bot id=7815606139
ERROR:aiogram.event:Cause exception while process update id=478623881 by bot id=7815606139
TelegramRetryAfter: Telegram server says - Flood control exceeded on method 'EditMessageText' in chat 6523126372. Retry in 224 seconds.
Original description: Too Many Requests: retry after 224

